# Program mostly using if and else statements isn't executing correctly

Tags: c++

I am currently trying to write a program that takes three integers, and sorts them from least to greatest, then outputs them along with the original order that was typed. The program is very buggy e.g when i input "4 7 9" the program will sort it as "4 9 9". But if i do "65 32 11" then the program will sort it correctly as "11 32 65". I'm just wondering where I went wrong with my code and how I can improve upon it and for future projects.

```
cout << "Please input 3 integers with a space inbetween them.\n";
int v1;
int v2;
int v3;

int smallest = 0;
int middle = 0;
int largest = 0;

cin >> v1 >> v2 >> v3;

    if (v1 <= v2 && v1 <= v3) {
        smallest = v1;
        if (v2 <= v3) {
            middle = v2;
            largest = v3;
        }
        else
            largest = v2;
        middle = v3;
    }

    else if (v2 <= v1 && v2 <= v3) {
        smallest = v2;
        if (v1 <= v3) {
            middle = v1;
            largest = v3;
        }
        else
            largest = v1;
        middle = v3;
    }
    else {
        smallest = v3;
        if (v1 <= v2) {
            middle = v1;
            largest = v2;
        }
        else
            largest = v1;
        middle = v2;
    }

cout << "Input values: " << v1 << ", " << v2 << ", " << v3 << '\n';
cout << "Sorted values: " << smallest << ", " << middle << ", " << largest << '\n';

keep_window_open();
}
```

Comment: It looks like those `else` blocks are all supposed to include both following lines but they do not. `middle` is always overwritten.

Comment: I agree with @FrançoisAndrieux. Replace all `else` by `else {...}`.

Comment: As a rule that I like to follow, *ALWAYS* use `{` and `}` on `if` and `else` blocks. You don't need to occupy more than one line, tho: you can write `} else {` on one line.

Comment: Also, you can use vector and sort it: it's already made, will not be buggy, and it will work with any quantity of numbers.

Comment: Recommendation: While learning always use the optional braces. They make whole families of common bugs impossible or obvious. In addition consider adding an automatic source code formatter to your tools. Run your code through the formatter and see if the indentation changes. If it does, you probably screwed up somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

```
cout << "Please input 3 integers with a space inbetween them.\n";
int v1;
int v2;
int v3;

int smallest = 0;
int middle = 0;
int largest = 0;

cin >> v1 >> v2 >> v3;

    if (v1 <= v2 && v1 <= v3) {
        smallest = v1;
        if (v2 <= v3) {
            middle = v2;
            largest = v3;
        }
```

Here `{}` are missing for else section

```
        else{
            largest = v2;
            middle = v3;
        }
    }

    else if (v2 <= v1 && v2 <= v3) {
        smallest = v2;
        if (v1 <= v3) {
            middle = v1;
            largest = v3;
        }
```

Here `{}` are missing for else section

```
        else{
            largest = v1;
            middle = v3;
            }
    }
    else {
        smallest = v3;
        if (v1 <= v2) {
            middle = v1;
            largest = v2;
        }
```

Here `{}` are missing for else section

```
        else{
            largest = v1;
            middle = v2;
            }
    }

cout << "Input values: " << v1 << ", " << v2 << ", " << v3 << '\n';
cout << "Sorted values: " << smallest << ", " << middle << ", " << largest << '\n';

keep_window_open();
}
```

If you look at your else section of the all the if else, you are missing `{}` That is messing up your largest and middle value.

More Information ...

```
if(condition)     /* if statement with condition */
    statement;    /* executes if the if condition is true even without the {} */
else              /* else statement when if condition is false */
    statement;    /* executes when else is true without the {} */
    statement;    /* Visually misguided but execution does not depend
                     upon the else statement, this line always gets executed,
                     compiler only looks at the first line after if else without {} */
```

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that popped out at me is your else statements. In C/C++, `else` statements without brackets will execute the next statement as it's condition fulfillment. It will not execute more than one statement if no braces are present. This is problematic in your code because your `middle` value is overwritten regardless of your second-level `if` statements. For reference, a [discussion](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16528/single-statement-if-block-braces-or-no) can be viewed on SO's Software Engineering Page.

Replace

```
if (v1 <= v2 && v1 <= v3) {
    smallest = v1;
    if (v2 <= v3) {
        middle = v2;
        largest = v3;
    }
    else
        largest = v2;
    middle = v3;
}
```

With

```
if (v1 <= v2 && v1 <= v3) {
    smallest = v1;
    if (v2 <= v3) {
        middle = v2;
        largest = v3;
    }
    else
    {
        largest = v2;
        middle = v3;
    }
```

As a side note, you should consider implementing a Radix sort if you would like to account for a higher-number of digits. Click here for a [Radix Sorting Algorithm Tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/radix-sort/)